# What using directive do I use for newly added dll reference

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and have added a reference to an sdk, but don't know what using directive to use.  How do I find out what I should use?

The properties of the reference show the following:

```
Name:                ServiceProvider
Aliases:             global
Copy Local:          True
Embed Interop Types: False
File Type:           Assembly
Identity:            ServiceProvider
Path:                C:\dmcc-dotnet-sdk\Dashboard\ServiceProvider.dll
resolved:            True
```

I have tried:

```
using ServiceProvider;
```

but that gives me:

> The type or namespace name 'ServiceProvider' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The assembly shows up in the object browser, so its all there ready to be used.

Somebody, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Avaya documentation. The name of an assembly *(a dll file)* [might not be the same](http://atornblad.se/finding-the-right-namespace) as the namespace that its classes belong to. For example, the **mscorlib** reference contains classes belonging to a lot of different `Microsoft.` and `System.` namespaces.

**Double-click the reference** in your solution explorer. That will open the **object browser**, which tells you about what namespaces and classes are available.

**Solution Explorer**

[image: Solution explorer references section]

**Object Browser**

[image]

In this screenshot, I have expanded the **System.Web** assembly *(the System.Web.dll)* to look at what namespaces are in it. I can see namespaces `Microsoft.Runtime.Hosting`, `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper`, `System` and so on. You should see some namespaces starting with `Avaya.`.

If that doesn't help, it might be the case that your target architecture doesn't match that of the dll file.

[Avaya documentation](https://www.devconnectprogram.com/media/global/DMCCUserDocumentation/doc/N.Avaya.ApplicationEnablement.DMCC.htm) suggests the namespace is `Avaya.ApplicationEnablement.DMCC`

Comment: double clicking the reference, just takes me to the object browser

Comment: @Graham you can see the namespaces in object browser.

Comment: And what does the object browser tell you? Expand the assembly to see all the namespaces.

Comment: The object browser gives me no namespace

Comment: OK - I take it back, there is that namespace in the object browser.  It was just lost amongst everything else and I'm guessing that the curly braces symbol indicates that it is a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the documentation of the assembly you're referencing. Often the namespace will be the same as the assembly name, but not necessarely.